# how to bind ComboBox with DataTable

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have the DataTable with following columns:

id, Name, Description, ParentId

and would like to create a WPF control (.NET 4.0 framework) which implements a combobox which displays the names which are bound to values of id. So when the user selects a name displayed in the combobox the behind logic has to retrieve its id value.

I would be very thankful if anyone could show the way of doing the described above.

Comment: you don't need to create a control for that...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like so:

In your XAML file, put:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="id" />
```

In your code behind, put:

```
myComboBox.ItemsSource = myTable;
```

(myTable being a reference to the table you mentioned)

Then you can reach the id of the currently selected person in the combo box using the expression:

```
NameComboBox.SelectedValue
```

Comment: DataTable cannot be bind directly.  You have to bind the myTable.DefaultView or IEnumerable from myTable.AsEnumerable().

Comment: The ItemsSource can also be set in XAML: ItemsSource="{Binding myProperty, Mode=OneWay}". As Nps/Igor notes the property should return a DataView rather than a DataTable.

Comment: Why is this accepted as answer ? DataTable cannot be bind like this to Combobox...

Answer (score 4):

MVVM pattern solution

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox 
   x:Name="myComboBox" 
   DisplayMemberPath="Name"
   SelectedValuePath="id"
   ItemsSource="{Binding myDataTable}"      
   SelectedValue="{Binding theID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
>
```

"Name" and "id" are columns in myDataTable.

**Code behind:**

```
private MyViewModel _myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
this.DataContext = _myViewModel;
```

**MyViewModel class**

```
public DataTable myDataTable { get; set; }
public short theID { get; set; }
```

The selected value (row) under the "id" column gets assign to 'theID'.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void InitCountry()
    {
        BasicData basicData = new DAL.BasicData();
        DataTable CountryListDT = basicData.GetCountryList();
        txtCountry.SelectedIndex = 0;
        txtCountry.ItemsSource = CountryListDT.DefaultView;
    }

    private void txtCountry_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BasicData basicData = new DAL.BasicData();
        object obj = (object)e.AddedItems;
        Int32 CountId = (Int32)txtCountry.SelectedValue;
        InitProvince(CountId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**My XAML:**

```
 <ComboBox  Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="listStatus" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" SelectionChanged="listStatus_SelectionChanged" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Status" SelectedValuePath="StatusID" />
```

**The Code Behind:**

```
private void Bind_StatusList()
{
  Service1 serv = new Service1();
  dtStatus = serv.GetStatuses(); // a WCF service getting the DataTable from a view from the database.
  listStatus.ItemsSource = dtStatus.DefaultView;
}
```

This doesn't give a selected option when the window starts, but at least the list of Status is showing when I click the comboBox.