# Property bound to radcombobox not updated after item selected

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik

After selecting an item from a combobox, the property attached does not get updated as expected.  It's a noob error but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong, please.

XAML:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cboFinish" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Text="{Binding finish}" TextSearch.TextPath="theFinish" IsEditable="True" >
```

Property:

```
    Private _finish As String
Public Property finish As String
    Get
        Return _finish
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _finish = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("finish")
    End Set
End Property
```

In the dropdown closed event of the combo, I have to assign the property the value of cboFinish.Text to update the property to the new selection.  This code shouldn't need to be done, does it?
                thisOrderFinish.finish = cboFinish.Text

I thought that was the job of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comboboxes seem to be the only control where I've noticed this behavior.  Textbox properties updated as expected.

Thanks for your help.

Edits:
Combobox binding:

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        cboFinish.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView

        cboFinish.IsTextSearchEnabled = True
        cboFinish.StaysOpenOnEdit = True
```

Modified XAML:

Comment: Have a look at [selection](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/features/selection).

Comment: Thanks.  I changed my xaml to include SelectedValuePath=finish.  That didn't fix it.  I changed it to SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=finish}".  That didn't either.  I am getting an error message that might help though. "BindingExpression path error: 'Charcoal Gray' property not found on 'object'" .  Charcoal Gray is the currently selected item and I'm attempting to change it to 'Gray'.  So, somehow the item shown in the combobox is getting confused with the property name.  It's assumed that "Charcoal Gray" is the property name???

Comment: I'm a noob at wpf and would really appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Text` property of a `ComboBox` isn't the best choice for retrieving the selected value.

Depending on the Items in the Collection you should use:

- `SelectedItem` : when the Items in the Collection are strings
- `SelectedValue` : when the type of the Items is *'SomeClass'*. ComboBox showing the same property for each Item. This property path is set with `SelectedValuePath`.

Each of the 4 possibilities in the [tutorial](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/features/selection#using-the-selecteditem) stand on their own (you shouldn't combine them).

You probably want `SelectedItem`

```
<telerik:RadComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding finish}"/>
```

Comment: The combobox is bound to a data table.  Using the tutorial for SelectedItem, Dim theFinish As OrderFinish = TryCast(cboFinish.SelectedItem, OrderFinish) should return "Gray" but instead returns "Nothing".    I tried this but got "Nothing" as well:  Dim selectedItem As RadComboBoxItem = TryCast(cboFinish.SelectedItem, OrderFinish).  Thanks for your help.  I'll have to dig into this some more.  I'm sure your answer will help someone.

Comment: @EManning A `DataTable` row can be seen like a Class where the Columns are the Class Properties : `SelectedValue`. Found [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749842/how-to-bind-combobox-with-datatable).

Comment: Yes, I saw it too and tried that approach.  But then the combobox had no items to select and the text part of the combo was blank.  See my edits.  I added how the combobox is bound and how I changed the XAML to match that example.

Comment: Telerik suggested setting the binding to two-way which solved the problem.  Text="{Binding finish, Mode=TwoWay}".  Since I'm a beginner to both WPF and OOP, I hope that this is the best way to do this task.  All I want to do is to update the underlying property when an item is selected.  I suppose it all depends on the results you want.  Thanks for your help.