# content in combobox doesnt display data from data base but system.data.datarowview

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get data form my data base to be displayed in my combobox but it says system.data.datarowview instead can someone please give me a helping hand.

```cs
public DataView GetAllCountries()
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select partij from partijen";
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
            dtData.Load(reader);
            connection.Close();

            return dtData.DefaultView;
        }
```

Comment: Set the combobox DisplayMember property to the "partij" string. In this way you tell the combo what field it should use to display

Comment: What exactly is your SQL connection string? Where's your try catch in case an exception is raised, and can you verify once you execute connection.Open() that the connection did indeed open?

Comment: @D.Foley There would be an error instead of current behavior if connection was not open.

Comment: Those things are good practice, but they are not relevant to the question, so maybe @GRAR took them out to show us where the problem is?

Comment: @Crowcoder The paranoid programmer in me would want to check SqlConnection.State..  just to clarify, when you say "it says system.data.datarowview instead" do you mean that text is showing verbatim in the combobox?

Comment: @D.Foley if you don't tell the control what DisplayMember to use it will `ToString()` the object, and that results in the fully qualified class name unless there is an override to `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from: [how to bind ComboBox with DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749842/how-to-bind-combobox-with-datatable)

I've gone ahead and created my own data table in memory since I can't exactly replicate your environment.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Countries");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CountryName"));

        DataRow australia = dt.NewRow();
        australia["CountryName"] = "Australia";
        dt.Rows.Add(australia);

        DataRow japan = dt.NewRow();
        japan["CountryName"] = "Japan";
        dt.Rows.Add(japan);

        cmbAllData.DisplayMemberPath = "CountryName";
        cmbAllData.SelectedValuePath = "Australia";

        cmbAllData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

So what seems to be the key here is setting the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath as well as ComboBox.ItemSource. After I do that the "system.data.datarowview" doesn't appear any more and you see the underlying rows of the data table.

You're returning the DefaultView which is okay, you just need to implement the aforementioned logic I outlined after your call to GetAllCountries.

Hopefully this will solve your issue for you, if anything isn't clear don't hesistate to ask for clarification.